# Count previous null values in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table that is sorted by the 'date' column

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 10 |
| 1/2/2023 |  |
| 1/3/2023 |  |
| 1/4/2023 | 20 |
| 1/5/2023 |  |
| 1/6/2023 | 40 |
| 1/7/2023 | 42 |
| 1/8/2023 | 3 |
| 1/9/2023 |  |
| 1/10/2023 | 1 |

I want to create a result like this. Where 'counts' column is the number of rows immediately above the current row that has null in 'value' column.

| date | value | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 10 | 0 |
| 1/4/2023 | 20 | 2 |
| 1/6/2023 | 40 | 1 |
| 1/7/2023 | 42 | 0 |
| 1/8/2023 | 3 | 0 |
| 1/10/2023 | 1 | 1 |

Can this be done with a query in redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked the question for window functions so you see this was likely to be solved.

Here's a solution (I changed date to dt and value to val as using key words as column names is generally not where you want to go):

```
with prec_null as (
select *, 
  count(case when val is null then 1 else null end)
    over (order by dt rows unbounded preceding) as cnt
from test )
select dt, val, cnt - coalesce(lag(cnt) over(order by dt), 0) as cnt
from prec_null 
where val is not null
order by dt;
```